# PHP file zipping with native library

Tags: php, file, zip

someone would tell me what is going on here:

```
if($attach and $attachTemp){

  move_uploaded_file($attachTemp,'static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach);

  $dataAttach['attach'] = $lastIdInsert."_".$attach;
  $updateAttach = $this->model_schemas->update($lastIdInsert,$data=array('download'=>'1'));
  /*ZIP IT*/
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  $zip->open('static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach);
  $zip->addFile('static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach,$lastIdInsert.".zip");

  $zip->close();

}
```

It doesn't zips the files in that directory.

Then i receive2  errors:

```
Message: ZipArchive::addFile() [ziparchive.addfile]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object
Message: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object
```

files are moved but not zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the flags as create or overwrite. You can do this by;

```
$zip->open('static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach, 
           ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
```

Comment: Also, check return status of the open() function. `if ($zip->open('static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach, 
           ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE)`

Comment: @Faruk Sahin  this doesn't prints anything ($zip->open('static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE){ echo "true";}

Comment: any suggestion? the file is not zipped as i can see in direcotry there is no zip file

Comment: Shouldn't it be == TRUE instead !== TRUE ?

Comment: sure what about chmod ... i have 644 on files when moved to folder maybe it can be the problem?

Comment: Actually your .zip file and the file that you want to add to zip has the same name, "'static/downloads/'.$lastIdInsert."_".$attach". Did you notice that? There might be something going wrong there.

Comment: but i use $lastIdInsert.".zip"

Comment: Use .zip filename in the open, that's the name of the zip file. In the addFile method add the file you want to be included in the zip.